REACT NATIVE 0.74.3 Signed Release APK: No cached version available for offline mode
I am using React Native Latest version 0.74.3 for developing an APP. My App works fine if I ran this on Emulator with np react-native run-android.
When I try to generate the Signed APK for Android using Android Studio I am facing issue, but same android studio works fine for generating a signed apk for my another react native project which was developed in 0.74.2.
here is the Build Error on Release.
"Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-android-0.74.3-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.74.3) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=release, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download react-android-0.74.3-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.74.3): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Failed to transform hermes-android-0.74.3-release.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.74.3) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=release, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download hermes-android-0.74.3-release.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.74.3): No cached version available for offline mode

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output."

I tried Google search everything but can;t resolve this issue windows defender is turn off. My Android studio must download files I think there is some issue with 0.74.3 version.

No cached version available for offline mode -> Disable Offline Mode.

Yes I checked in Tools/Other WIndows >Gradle My offline Mode was enabled.
Thanks for your Responce
